# Failed jpa query : Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I want to get rooms by HospitalId, there relation between classes like it looks below:

```
@Entity(name = "rooms")
@Table( name = "rooms",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "roomNumber")

        })
public class Room {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long idRoom;

    private  String roomNumber;

    @ManyToOne
            (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "idhospital")
    private Hospital hospital;
```

this is the query i used :

```
@Query("select s from rooms s where s.hospital.idHospital =:hospital")
      List<Room> findRoomsByHospital( @Param("hospital") Long hospital);
```

Error in the back :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
```

Is send data but  wrong form  to the frontend :

**error**

[image]

I really need help can't understand how to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fount the problem :The repitation of data

Solution in to add this notation `@JsonIgnore`  like this :

```
 @ManyToOne
            (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "idhospital")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Hospital hospital;
```

This is used for to restrict the data to repeat itself

Answer (score 0):

I think you are query is not correct. You have used `rooms` there without using nativeQuery=true.

you can try below in `RoomRepository`

```
@Query("select s from Room s where s.hospital.idHospital =:hospital")
List<Room> findRoomsByHospital( @Param("hospital") Long hospital);
```

changed `rooms` to `Room`

Alternatively, you can try query by a method as shown below, you don't need to use the `@Query` in this case.

If you are passing `hospitalId` long use below

```
List<Room> findRoomsByHospitalIdHospital ( @Param("idHospital") Long hospital);
```

If you are passing `hospital` Object use below

```
List<Room> findRoomsByHospital ( @Param("Hospital ") Hospital hospital);
```

Comment: I have rooms in database not Room

Comment: if you use native query then you need to use rooms

Comment: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Hospital (n/a)]

Comment: Hospital in object but the attribut in the database in Long

Comment: You are passing `hospital Id` or whole Hospital object?

Comment: Edited the answer if you are passing `Hospital ` object

Comment: Ihad this error:       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roomRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List com.bezkoder.springjwt.repository.RoomRepository.findRoomsByHospital(com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Hospital) but parameter 'Optional[hospital ]' not found in annotated query 'select s from room s where s.hospital.idhospital =:hospital'!

Comment: I will get rooms belong to the hospital on the current user in which I will pass the idhospital in function parameters